# How to programmatically manipulate and resend a heavy javascipt post request?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, playwright, browser-automation

I am trying to write a script which captures post requests and manipulate them and resend them to the server. The page has heavy javascripts and it is hard to emulate the behavior with low-level libraries like "requests".
It is quite straightforward to use selenium and puppeteer to login to website and fill and send the form in order to send the post request, but it is not clear how to capture the post request and manipulate it in my script?
Do you have any suggested API in python or Node in order to capture and manipulate the network requests and resend them?
Any help is really appreciated,
Best Regards

Comment: You can add/remove fields from the DOM.  (For example adding a hidden field set to a certain value and remove the one that you are replacing...OR just changing the value of the field)  You should provide more details about what POST values you are replacing.  (...and maybe why)

Comment: Dear @pcalkins, I,m trying to test a website with unpredicted values in some fields. DOM is quite slow and I prefer the ability to manipulate request in my script. There are also hidden fields which are calculated by javascript.

Comment: You should probably build your own mock JS POSTs.  Then change the handler accordingly.  For instance if the JS function that sends is called "SendForm()", create a function called "SendFormTest()" and use that as your mock call.

Comment: Puppeteer and Playwright both have request interception, google that and you'll find something